# I am trying to send values using GET method, but Rails insist to call the POST method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, post, get

I don't understand why it is happening. Here is my form:

```
<%= form_tag controller: :static_pages, action: :index, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search_text %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", id: :search_button %>
<% end %>
```

However, instead of sending the valeu of `search_text` through the URL, it is calling the post method and sending the `method=get` in the URL.

```
http://localhost:3000/static_pages/index?method=get
```

Any idea the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interpreting the `method: :get` as part of the route the form should go to, rather than as additional options to `form_tag` itself. Wrap `controller: :static_pages, action: :index` in a hash and add parentheses to the method call. Then it should work:

```
<%= form_tag( {controller: :static_pages, action: :index}, method: :get ) do %>
```

Comment: Whoops! Yeah, the parser assumes that curly braces following a method call are a block rather than a hash. Wrapping the method call in parentheses should fix it. I've updated my answer.